# A function for checking if a list's length is larger than a given number gets into an infinite loop when entering an infinite list as a parameter

Tags: haskell, infinite-loop

I have the following function:

```
longer x y | y < 0 = True
           | length x > y = True
           | length x <= y = False
```

Where `x` is type `[a]` and `y` is type `Int`.

This function works fine for finite lists but doesn't evaluate and goes into an infinite loop when I enter an infinite list. What other approach should I try?

My attempt:

In the case of `longer [1..] 10`, I would start at the first value, compare the length of the list (so `[1]`) with 10, if the length is smaller, then move on to the first two values, compare the list's (so `[1,2]`) length with 10, see that the statement is still false, moving on to the first three values etc. I think recursion might be the correct way to approach this problem of mine.

Comment: Hint: how do you check whether a list's length is longer than 0? Do you really need `length` for that? And how does that help solving the problem given?

Comment: `length` diverges on infinite lists, so you can't use it. You could try explicit pattern matching and recursion -- this approach should be the default approach to list exercises, since most of them can be solved in this way. This task can indeed be solved in such a way. Alternatively, one could try combining `drop`, and `null` -- both work fine on infinite lists.

Comment: Good start, but “then move on to the first two values, compare the list's (so `[1,2]`) length with `10`” is redundant work. You've already ticked off the `1` at that point, haven't you?

Comment: Now, my code looks like this: `longer (x:xs) y | y < 0 = error "negative value" | length [x] > y = True | length [x] <= y = longer (xs) y` and it's still in an infinite loop and I don't know where and how to put in the case where it returns`False`. Also, it doesn't work for one element long lists anymore.

Comment: That's almost the correct solution, only you need to remember when you've popped off the leading `x` that also influences the length that you're comparing against. And, `length [x]` is simply `1`, always.

Comment: I think when `y < 0`, I'd prefer this function to return `True` rather than an error. After all, surely the length of every list is bigger than any negative number!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You see, if a list is passed to a function, it can be of two shapes, either it is empty

```
length [] y = undefined
```

or it consists of a value and the rest of the list

```
length (x:xs) y = undefined
```

These are the only two cases, because the list data type is defined that way:

```
Prelude> :info []
data [] a = [] | a : [a]    -- Defined in `GHC.Types'
```

So you have already made progress by splitting your original problem into two smaller parts. And you are probably able to implement the first case (the empty list). But note that you have also made progress for the second case. While previously you knew nothing of the original list `x` (which is better named `xs` instead), you now know that the original list is of shape `x : xs`. Here `x` is the first item of the list and `xs` is the remaining list. In particular you know now, that the passed list was at least of size 1. And this is true regardless of the remaining list `xs`. Are you now able to implement

```
length (x:_) 0 = undefined
```

If so, what about the case where `y` is not zero:

```
length (x:xs) y = undefined
```

Can you ask a new question about `xs` and `y` instead of `x:xs` and `y`? Remember, that you know that `xs` is one item shorter than `x : xs`.

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer, the finished code is here: `longerThan [] y = False longerThan (x:_) 0 = True
longerThan (x:xs) y | y < 0 = error "negative value" | otherwise = longerThan (xs) (y-1)`